# How to know what to use for fabricjs custom build

Tags: fabricjs

Since fabric js doesn't support tree-shaking via es6 modules for bundle size reduction i tried to do a custom build of fabricjs via website (http://fabricjs.com/build/) and via command line build and can't figure out which modules I need as I keep getting errors. I use

> node build.js modules=text,circle,image,rect,line,image_filters

since to my understanding I dont use anything else. Then I got an error that sort of indicated I would need to import `animation` module too - even though I don't use animations from my pov. I did that an indeed the error disappeared and now I get `this.drawSelectionBackground is not a function` and have no clue to which package it belongs so I wonder hot to figure that out - or do I really have to just go for trial and error?

Comment: you should post the errors you get in the question. And if you answered yourself, post an answer. It will help future readers to both find the question (with the actual error) and see it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out it's the interaction module that I need to import even though I dont use interactions...
Pretty weird...

Comment: It would have taken me at least a day to figure this out. Thanks. Apparently need interaction module for basically anything.